# Computing the maximum of $\left|\ln{\frac{2}{2-z}}\right|$ on $|z|=r$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $r>1$. Setting
\begin{equation*} f(z)=\ln{\frac{2}{2-z}},\end{equation*} one can get that
\begin{equation*} f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{2^k k},\end{equation*} since $f$ is holomorphic in $C_2=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<2\right\}$. Noting that
\begin{align*}
\left|f(z)\right|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^k}{2^k k}\right| 
\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{|z|^k}{2^k k},
\end{align*}
we get
\begin{equation*}
  \max_{|z|=r}\left|f(z)\right| \leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{r^k}{2^k k}=\ln{\frac{2}{2-r}}.  
\end{equation*}
Given that for $z=r$,
\begin{equation*}
\left|f(z)\right|=\left|\ln{\frac{2}{2-r}}\right|=\ln{\frac{2}{2-r}},
\end{equation*}
as $1<r<2$, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
\max_{|z|=r}\left|f(z)\right| =\ln{\frac{2}{2-r}}.
\end{equation*}
I know that this is not the standard way to obtain the maximum. I should begin by writting
\begin{equation*} z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta),\hspace{0.15cm}0\leq\theta\leq \pi,\end{equation*}
as $|z|=r$. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You wrote $r>1$ but you use formula which is valid for $0\leq r<2$.

Comment: Starting with $r>1$ is general as $r$ refers to a radius. The fact that $f$ is holomorphic in $C_2$ urges us to use that $1<r<2$.

Comment: Are you sure about that?